# Gibt es etwas besseres als »hm-hm« um im Chat Aufmerksamkeit auszudrücken?

Tags: colloquial, writing, interjection

Was für ein Wort kann man im Chat verwenden, wenn man bestätigen möchte, dass man Nachrichten erhalten und deren Inhalt aufgefasst hat, jedoch ohne sie zu bewerten? Etwa *Ja, ich lese noch mit.*

In einem Gespräch (in persona) wird das wohl üblicherweise mit Augenkontakt und diesem ganz leichten, fast nur angedeuteten Nicken übermittelt. Oder mit diesem gewissen Geräusch (oder ist es gar ein Wort?), das ich mit »hm-hm« oder »mhm« beschreiben würde. Und das ist auch das beste, was mir für den Chat einfällt: »hm-hm«.

- »Aha« passt nur, wenn etwas beantwortet/erklärt wurde (und in Chats könnte es leicht missverstanden werden).
- »Okay« drückt eine Bestätigung aus.

Eine Alternative wäre, auf die Nachrichten einzugehen (»Oha!«, »Nicht ernsthaft!«, »Gut so«, »Oh, oh, oh«, »Und dann?«, …), aber das ist zu aufwändig und wohl auch heuchlerisch für Triviales.

Comment: "ok" sagen viele in Gesprächen aber auch als Bestätigung, dass man verstanden hat, nicht zwangsweise als Zustimmung. Das kann man daher grundsätzlich auch im Chat sagen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde behaupten, dass es ein grundsätzliches Problem deines Gesprächspartners ist, wenn er von dir im Chat konstant Signale für deine Aufmerksamkeit erwartet.

Zum einem gibt es **Aktivitätsindikatoren** wie Ampelanzeigen und clientseitige Nachrichten im Stil von *"mehrere Benutzer schreiben gerade"* in den meisten Programmen oder es haben sich Umgehungslösungen wie z. B. das Suffix `|afk` im IRC eingebürgert, um Inaktivität bzw. Abwesenheit zu kommunizieren.

Wenn es um besonders wichtige Angelegenheiten geht, könnte man den Gesprächspartner vor Beginn Folgendes fragen (oder man verschickt eine angemessene E-Mail mit Terminvorschlag):

> Darf ich deine *ungeteilte* Aufmerksamkeit in Anspruch nehmen?

Nach einer Bestätigung sollte dann eine Unterbrechung oder Beendigung entsprechend angekündigt oder mitgeteilt werden.

Dies wäre eine sprachunabhängige und gleichzeitig elegante Lösung. Üblicherweise besteht dafür aber kaum ein Anlass. Wer seinen Gesprächspartner kennt und respektiert, kann auch Geduld aufbringen und auf eine Antwort warten oder zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt nachfragen.

Answer (score 3):

Ein Chat ist kein unmittelbares persönliches Gespräch. Wie LiveWireBT gesagt hat, geht man im Allgemeinen also nicht davon aus, dass die Aufmerksamkeit ungeteilt auf einem Chat liegt.

Sollte es in einer Situation aber dennoch wichtig sein, diese Aufmerksamkeit zu signalisieren, so hat man dafür zwei Möglichkeiten.

1. `k` als Kurzform von `ok`, was aber nur verwendet werden sollte, wenn es nicht mit Zustimmung verwechselt werden kann.
2. Ein Signal, auf das man sich vorher oder per älterer Konvention geeinigt hat. Das kann zum Beispiel `hm-mm` sein, oder auch ein einzelnes `.`. Jedenfalls gibt es im Gegensatz zum gegenteiligen `afk` oder Schlafsmileys keinen Standard hierfür.

Comment: auch häufig in (eher internationalen) chatrooms gesehen: `kk`, `ye`. Für mich persönlich drückt `hm` eher eine Ablehnung aus, aber das könnte auch nur an mir liegen..

Answer (score 0):

Wenn es nur darum geht den Gesprächspartner die Anwesenheit vor dem eigenen Computer zu signalisieren, reicht es wenn du diesen Text sendest:

> .

Einfach nur ein Punkt. Dann weiß dein Gesprächspartner dass du noch da bist. Aber wie im »echten« Leben auch, ist es vielleicht höflicher wenn du ein ganz kurzes Feedback gibts. Mit

> ok

Drückst du aus dass du da bist, die Nachricht empfangen hast und ihr (zumindest jetzt) nicht widersprichst. Du kannst natürlich auch schreiben:

> Schreib weiter, ich bin noch da und lese mit.